# Record loopback audio with sdl2 in c++

Tags: c++, audio, sdl-2, audio-recording

Is there a way to record loopback audio with sdl2 in c++?

Comment: Do you mean recording audio that's played by other software?

Comment: i mean recording audio that's being played in general, like from the master channel

Comment: According to https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/wasapi-loopback/23205 it has been discussed but I don't think it's implemented. Does it have to be with sdl2? I can post an answer explaining how to record loopback audio on windows with WASAPI if that's useful.